# Single queue instruction issuing in computer architecture

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-pipelines

I am working on this paper titled “the microarchitecture of superscalar processors by Smith and Sohi” and it says that there are 3 methods of organizing instruction queue. I know that the method “Multiple queues” is the same as the method “Scoreboard” and also the method “Multiple reservation stations” is the same as the method “Tomasulo”, but I can’t find any thing about the method “Single queue”. All it says is that there is a bit for reserving and clearing the reservation. But i don’t know how it works. Is there any design or anything that shows the architecture of this method?
[image: I need to know how part (a) works]